# default thumbnail for all posts in same category

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

My Wordpress site use first image as post thumbnail, code:

```
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
function get_first_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches[1][0];

if(empty($first_img)) {
$first_img = "/path/to/default.png";
}
return $first_img;
}
```

Some posts have no image in its content, so i want to use different default thumbnails for them: posts in category A use picture1, posts in cagory B use category2...

How can I do this?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, It's my code:

```
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
function get_first_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches[1][0];

if(empty($first_img)) {
  $categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
if( $category->name == 'Category A' ){ $first_img = "/path/to/default1.png";}  
elseif ( $category->name == 'Category B' ){ $first_img = "/path/to/default2.png";}
else {$first_img = "/path/to/default3.png";}
}
}
}
return $first_img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current post category first, then, make a if statement in your code.

Check this link : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/#comment-305

Answer (score 0):

How about this, here we are using **has_post_thumbnail** to check for image attachments, if none exist we are setting up the image and image source. From there we check for category assignment, if there are no category matches we use a default thumbnail.

```
<?php
if ( ! has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $themefolder = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    echo '<img src="' . $themefolder . '/images/';
    if ( is_category( 'Category A' ) ) {
        echo 'no-image-a.png';
    } elseif ( is_category( 'Category B' ) ) {
        echo 'no-image-b.png';    
    } else {
        echo 'no-image.png'; 
    }
    echo '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '">' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm using first_image for my site, I want to keep it, I don't know how to apply your code for first_image. Thanks

Comment: You could replace:

    `if(empty($first_img)) {
        $first_img = "/path/to/default.png";
    }
    return $first_img;
    }`

with:

    `if(! empty($first_img)) {
        return $first_img;
    }
    }`

Then use my code snippet independently within the relevant page/post template.